# How to pass search criteria from one site to another site and load

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

In my application we have address displayed on the screen, we have dropdown with links when user clicks on the link it should open the site in new tab and do the search with the address.

Lets say I have address "3301 s finely Rd, Chicago IL" and link as "www.zillow.com" how to pass the address to this site and load the page?

Comment: have you tried `querystring`?

Comment: tried with querystring but it didn't worked. First of all we dont know how the other site is expecting parameters ?

Comment: Why you have tagged this question with `rest` and `web-api`, are you using any of that, or other site need parameters to be posted with `web-api`?

Comment: I thought the best way to fix this issue is to use their API, am using asp.net MVC && angular

Comment: Then you should look for documentation of their `API` to see `how to pass parameter` ( querystring , Post request with JSON or xml format), and use required one.

Comment: am asking the suggestion, which is best way to solve this ?

Comment: You have to rely on their API, there is no other way to follow , as far as i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by creating the passing the parameters the way zillow accepts. This is the url generated when we search any property on the zillow site.

```
http://www.zillow.com/homes/{address}-{city}-{state}-{zip}_rb
```

and opened the using window.open()